# How can I use mypy when overriding coroutine of supertypes?

Tags: python, mypy

There's one class that extends another and overrides a coroutine that returns an iterator:

```
class Repository:
     async def run(self, query: Query) -> AsyncIterator[int]:
...

class MyRepository(Repository):
     async def run(self, query: Query) -> AsyncIterator[int]:
...
```

Running mypy returns this error:

```
error: Return type "AsyncIterator[int]" of "run" incompatible with return type "Coroutine[Any, Any, AsyncIterator[int]]" in supertype "Repository"
```

[Coroutines are typed like normal functions](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheat_sheet_py3.html#coroutines-and-asyncio), so I'm not sure what the right approach is.

Using ABC classes won't fix it:

```
class Repository(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    async def run(self, query: Query) -> AsyncIterator[int]:
```

Answer (score 5):

Found it thanks to [this issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5385#issuecomment-407281656):

> I think you shouldn't make the protocol function async def, but just
>   def. Conceptually, an async generator is a callable that returns an
>   AsyncIterator (or more precisely, an AsyncGenerator). But an async def
>   function without a yield returns an Awaitable of whatever its declared
>   return type is, so that's how mypy interprets your protocol.

So, changing `async def run` with `def run` works.

Comment: Be aware that this may cause pylint to fail if you child class method needs to be async.